# Polymer app won't load in Safari (pre-1.0)

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

A load of errors, and my app won't load. True on desktop (OSX El Capitan) and mobile (iOS9).

http://d.pr/i/1lvBa

Errors like:

```
TypeError: Attempting to change configurable attribute of unconfigurable property.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: HTMLImports
    (anonymous function)
    atEndOfMicrotask

TypeError: document.registerElement is not a function. (In 'document.registerElement('polymer-element', {prototype: prototype})', 'document.registerElement' is undefined)
```

And more...

My Polymer (Dart) version is 0.16.3+3.

Comment: The screenshot link is broken.

Comment: Fixed: http://d.pr/i/1lvBa. I think SO re-writes my Droplr link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you run into this issue https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/538

> It appears that problem is in outdated web_components, i got it all
>   working on iOS 9 and OSX 10.11 by overriding web_components in my yams
>   file by adding:
>
> dependency_overrides: web_components: "^0.12.0+3"

Comment: Pub build errors: `Could not find asset web_components|lib/README.md.
package:pub/src/barback/pub_package_provider.dart 112  PubPackageProvider._assertExists
package:pub/src/barback/pub_package_provider.dart 106  PubPackageProvider.getAsset.<async>
This is an unexpected error. Please run

    pub --trace build --mode=debug

and include the results in a bug report on http://dartbug.com/new.
`

Comment: You and me both! Bottom line, that override for web_components in that bug you linked to doesn't do it for me.

Comment: See https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/538#issuecomment-151572462. The error I noted above only occurred with `pub build --mode=debug`. Regular `pub build` fixed it. Works on Safari now!