# Run Polymer Dart from Cordova using pub serve

Tags: cordova, dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to run a polymer dart app from Cordova via `pub serve`.

Here's what I tried:

1. Used the generated polymer project from stagehand, latest web storm (11.0.3), latest dart dev build (1.14.0-dev.5.0).
2. Disabled app transport security (for iOS, plist entry, there's a [cordova plugin for that](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-transport-security)).
3. `config.xml`: I set both access origin, and allow navigation to `*`.
4. Set `<content src="http://localhost:8080/index.html" />` instead of `<content src="index.html" />` (also tried to put the LAN IP instead of localhost).
5. `csp: true` in *$dart2js* and *web_components* *transformers*.
6. Used `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag to allow pretty much everything.
7. Ran `pub serve --hostname 0.0.0.0`.
8. `cordova run ios` -> then I get a white blank app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "fix" was to use a later version of Cordova.

Had this issue with 5.1.1, when I updated to the latest (5.4.1 at the moment of writing), it works fine, didn't even need to re-create the Cordova project folder.

I went back and forth between these 2 versions to verify that this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of web_components are you using in your pubspec.yaml ?

According to this [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/538) and this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361258/polymer-app-wont-load-in-safari-pre-1-0) , maybe you may need to override the web_components version like this:

```
dependency_overrides: web_components: "^0.12.0+3"
```

Comment: Seems to be a different problem, I'm using "0.12.0+4", works fine in iOS Safari (Also OS X), but not in Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success wrapping my Polymer.dart app with Cordova.

Did you verify that your App Transport Security Settings are correct and that Allow Arbitrary Loads is YES? You say you used a plugin for that, but perhaps it wasn't set appropriately.

Did you enable CORS in your Dart server, so that your Cordova app can make requests of it?

Did you drop the output of `pub build` (in /build) into the platforms/ios//www folder of your Cordova project?

Comment: Thanks David, but I'm trying to use `pub serve`.
I know `pub build` works fine after copying resources to www.